# Reducing number of results returned from Full-Text query

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I'm using the CONTAINS keyword to search a SQL-Server full-text catalog.
The table I'm querying contains (among other columns) the textual column which is full-text-indexed, and a "added_date" column which represents the date the row was added (and has a normal index).

The table contains about 7M rows. Specific queries on the full-text catalog could return ~1M rows. I wish to use the "added_date" column to reduce the number of rows returned by the query.

The problem is that when I add the "added_date" condition, I see in the execution plan that the DB will query the table twice: once for the full-text catalog (called "Remote Scan" in the execution plan), and once for the date condition. This forces the DB to join results from both parts of the query, so no performance improvement is achieved.

Is there a way to force SQL Server to full-text-query only the rows which remains after the date condition was applied?

EDIT: the query looks like

`SELECT reason, added_date
FROM reasons_table
WHERE CONTAINS(reason, 'a_reason')
AND added_date > getdate()-5`

Comment: Pls, write you query and indexes you use.

Comment: according to this: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc917695.aspx 
what i'm trying to achieve is impossible:
Because the MSFTESQL service operates outside the database engine, SQL Server 2005 cannot extend predicates on SQL queries into the full-text search. As a result, even though your query may have additional conditions that significantly reduce the final number of rows returned by the query, the MSFTESQL service still returns all the matching keys for the target search.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've pointed out, this is pretty much impossible in the manner in which you're hoping.  Depending on the larger context of your situation, you have some options.  In fact, that article gives you some help.

Here are some ideas that come to mind when I read that article:

1. Embed the filter criteria in your text

   - Check out the "Consider embedding filter conditions as keywords in the indexed text" bullet in the article.
   - This essentially says you could consider putting your date as an easily-locatable string in the text.  E.g., "<DateAdded:YYYYMMDD>"  Something you can strip out before processing the text.
   - Probably not great for ranges, though the workaround for this is a coarser grained filter term.  I.e., instead of DateAdded:YYYYMMDD, use WeekAdded:YYYYWW, then you're pulling 7-14 days' worth off FTS and your `added_date` predicate can further narrow it.
   - Probably stops being practical well before 100 search terms.
   - Adding a filter criteria means running an update to add it to all 7m+ records
   - Otherwise, this seems closest in spirit to what you are after
2. Two tables - horizontal partition

   - If you chiefly look back only a few days, you can try simply keeping a second table with FTS with only the last *n* days of records.
   - May be a PITA to maintain.
3. Two tables - vertical partition

   - Split your table into 1 with the values you're going to filter by in SQL and another with the FTS text.  Then use CONTAINSTABLE to bring them together.
   - You are still doing 2 table hits.  The one benefit, though, is that your reduced table will be tighter, with more records per page, allowing less IO.
   - Admittedly, this improvement might not even be noticeable.  And for all that a covering index might be as good.
4. Live with it

   - Do you have the performance numbers to show that this double-read is resulting in a big loss in performance?  Assuming your PK is < 10 bytes and you have an index on your searched fields, I'd guess you'd need 20k+ filtered records returned to notice the extra read?

Do any of these work for your particular situation?

Comment: Actually, tip #3, along with some code modifications, can produce a far smaller table containing the FTS test, which can be later joined with the original table.
I shall try to implement this solution, or benchmark another indexing solution such as lucene.